# Migrate data to another database with different object names

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle, database-migration

We are working on a project to migrate our Oracle database to SQL Server. There are many off the shelf products that seem to do this such as Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant & Navicat premium for example.

One of the requirements of this migration is that we are changing the naming convention of the tables & columns as part of the transition.
In Oracle we currently have adopted the naming convention of:

Table: `T_USERS, T_REPORTS, T_USERS_REPORTS etc.`

Columns: `USER_ID, CREATE_DT etc.`

While moving to SQL Server we wish to adopt a SQL Server specific naming convention (Camel case):

Table: `Users, Reports, UsersReports etc.`

Columns: `UserId, CreateDt etc.`

Both of these tools mentioned seem to only create a SQL Server object with the exact same table & column names as part of the data migration process. Is it possible to create this sort of mapping with either of these two tools? Or is there a better tool available?

Both of these also do not feature incremental data migration. They are designed to completely clean out all records and then migrate all data. This is obviously not ideal for performance. Is there a tool that has a delta type migration where it will compare existing records on both target and source destinations?

Comment: Why is performance important? I guess you're only doing this once?

Comment: We wouldn't be doing this just once. The approach we'd ideally like to take is that we have migrate the production database at some point in time and then just before we switch the consuming applications to the SQL Server database we do a delta migration to make sure everything is in sync. Production database is about 20 million records.

Comment: Ok. I don't know any "of the shelf products" that can do that. It sounds like a typical SSIS - project to me.